# Anyone see anything wrong with my regex for port numbers?

Tags: regex

I made a regex for port numbers (before you say this is a bad idea, its going into a bigger regex for URL's which is much harder than it sounds).

My coworker said this is really bad and isn't going to catch everything. I disagree.

I believe this thing catches everything from 0 to 65535 and *nothing else,* and I'm looking for confirmation of this.

Single-line version (for computers):

```
/(^[0-9]$)|(^[0-9][0-9]$)|(^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$)|(^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)|((^[0-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)|(^6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)|(^65[0-4][0-9][0-9]$)|(^655[0-2][0-9]$)|(^6553[0-5]$))/
```

Human readable version:

```
/(^[0-9]$)|                           # single digit
 (^[0-9][0-9]$)|                      # two digit
 (^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$)|                 # three digit
 (^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)|            # four digit
 ((^[0-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)|      # five digit (up to 59999)
  (^6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]$)|          #            (up to 64999)
  (^65[0-4][0-9][0-9]$)|              #            (up to 65499)
  (^655[0-2][0-9]$)|                  #            (up to 65529)
  (^6553[0-5]$))/                     #            (up to 65535)
```

Can someone confirm that my understanding is correct (or otherwise)?

Comment: Whatever language you're using almost certainly has a better way to parse URLs in its libraries.

Comment: I don't think you need the nested parens.

Comment: It's kind of brute-force, but I think it would work.

Comment: Actually, I can deny your power. Even if that regex works (and I have no reason to doubt that it does), it's hideous, unreadable monstrosities like it that give regular expressions a bad name. TimP, for one, gives a more readable solution but my advice, not that you'll take it after I've just insulted you :-), is: if you want to parse a URL, use a parser. Then you can just allow the regex `^\d{1,5}$` (or `^0*\d{1,5}$` if you want to allow leading zeros) and check to ensure it's less than 64K _after_ the lexical phase.

Comment: Is this a proof of the kind *Because I can* ? "It is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail." -- law of the instrument.

Comment: Downvote removed because the offending material was edited away. Awesome edit summary Will!

Answer (score 26):

You could shorten it considerably:

```
^0*(?:6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])$
```

- no need to repeat the anchors every single time
- no need for lots of capturing groups
- no need to spell out repetitions.

Drop the leading `0*` if you don't want to allow leading zeroes.

This regex is also better because it matches the special cases (65535, 65001 etc.) first and thus avoids some backtracking.

Oh, and since you said you want to use this as part of a larger regex for URLs, you should then replace both `^` and `$` with `\b` (word boundary anchors).

---

**Edit:** @ceving asked if the repetition of `6553`, `655`, `65` and `6` is really necessary. The answer is no - you can also use a nested regex instead of having to repeat those leading digits. Let's just consider the section

```
6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}
```

This can be rewritten as

```
6(?:[0-4][0-9]{3}|5(?:[0-4][0-9]{2}|5(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[0-5])))
```

I would argue that this makes the regex even less readable than it already was. Verbose mode makes the differences a bit clearer. Compare

```
6553[0-5]       |
655[0-2][0-9]   |
65[0-4][0-9]{2} |
6[0-4][0-9]{3}
```

with

```
6 
(?:
 [0-4][0-9]{3}
|
 5
 (?:
  [0-4][0-9]{2}
 |
  5
  (?:
   [0-2][0-9]
  |
   3[0-5]
  )
 )
)
```

Some performance measurements: Testing each regex against all numbers from 1 through 99999 shows a minimal, probably irrelevant performance benefit for the nested version:

```
import timeit

r1 = """import re
regex = re.compile(r"0*(?:6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])$")"""

r2 = """import re
regex = re.compile(r"0*(?:6(?:[0-4][0-9]{3}|5(?:[0-4][0-9]{2}|5(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[0-5])))|[1-5][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])$")"""

stmt = """for i in range(1,100000):
    regex.match(str(i))"""

print(timeit.timeit(setup=r1, stmt=stmt, number=100))
print(timeit.timeit(setup=r2, stmt=stmt, number=100))
```

Output:

```
7.7265428834649
7.556472630353351
```

Comment: That's certainly more readable so, even though I doubt the sanity of the question :-), +1 for a good answer.

Comment: I am wondering if the repetition of 6553, 655, 65, 6 is really necessary.

Comment: @ceving: You're right, it isn't necessary. See my edit.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Is it faster to move the fixed numbers to the beginning? `6(?:5(?:5(?:3[0-5]|[0-2]\d)|[0-4]\d{2})|[0-4]\d{3})`

Comment: BTW: 0 is a reserved port and can not be used for a connection. This means it is [questionable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180492/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-tcp-port-0) to accept it as a port number.

Comment: @Tommy: you’re probably not testing the entire (top) regex but one of the excerpts from below.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - here's the test link to regex101 that uses my regex and tests it against 4500: https://regex101.com/r/uUm8aD/1

Comment: @TimPietzcker my bad. That website wasn't auto-updating the results after changing the regex. No matching string changed to a match after pressing enter. I am now using this too, thanks! EDIT: I think my issue might have been a newline in the box after the 4500, doh!

Answer (score 8):

Personally I would match just a number and then I would check with code that the number is in range.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it's easy to prove that it will validate any correct port: just generate each valid string and test that it passes. Making sure it doesn't allow anything that it shouldn't is harder though - obviously you can't test absolutely *every* invalid string. You should definitely test simple cases and anything which you think *might* pass incorrectly (or which would pass incorrectly with a lesser regex - "65536" being an example).

It will allow some slightly odd port specifications though - such as "0000". Do you *want* to allow leading zeroes?

You might also want to consider whether you actually need to specify ^ and $ separately for each case, or whether you could use `^(case 1)|(case 2)|...$`. Oh, and quantifiers could simplify the "1 to 4 digits" case too: `([0-9]{1,4})` will find between 1 and 4 digits.

(You might want to work on sounding a little less arrogant, by the way. If you're working with other people, communicating in a less aggressive way is likely to do more to improve everyone's day than just proving your regex is correct...)

Comment: +1 but besides validating with each valid string, OP should also test for invalid strings, especially boundary values. While he's at it, keeping the tone down wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @Lieven: Oh absolutely, invalid strings should definitely be tested. That was part of my point - he needs to work out whether "0000" should *be* invalid. Will edit to make that clearer.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with parsing it into a number and work with integer comparisons? (regardless of whether or not this will be part of a "larger" regex).

If I were to use regex, I would just use:

```
\d{1,5}
```

Nope, it doesn't check for "valid" port numbers (neither does yours). But it's much more legible and for practical purposes I'd say it's "good enough."

PS: I'd work on being more humble.

Answer (score 3):

A style note:

Repeating `[0-9]` over and over again is silly - something like `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` is much better written as `\d{3}`.

Comment: ...although sometimes `[0-9]` is better than `\d`, for example in .NET where `d` will also match digits like `۳` (indo-arabic 3) which you probably don't want matched.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(6553[0-5])|(655[0-2]\d)|(65[0-4]\d{2})|(6[0-4]\d{3})|([1-5]\d{4})|([1-9]\d{1,3})|(\d)$/
```

Comment: Just a little shorter after the second last OR `/^(6553[0-5])|(655[0-2]\d)|(65[0-4]\d{2})|(6[0-4]\d{3})|([1-5]\d{4})|(\d{1,4})$/`

Answer (score 0):

regex has many implement ,what the paltform. try below , remove blanks

```
^[1-5]?\d{1,4}|6([0-4]\d{3}|5([0-4]\d{2}|5([0-2]\d|3[0-5]))$
```

readable

```
^
[1-5]?\d{1,4}|
6(
 [0-4]\d{3}|
 5(
  [0-4]\d{2}|
  5(
   [0-2]\d|
   3[0-5]
  )
 )
$
```

Comment: Not bad, but you need another set of parentheses at the top level to make the anchors work right: `^(foo|bar)$`, not `^foo|bar$`

Comment: First regexp is broken. And the second also. The parenthesis following the 6 gets never closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [this](http://regexper.com/#6%28%3F%3A[0-4]%5Cd%7B3%7D%7C5%28%3F%3A[0-4]%5Cd%7B2%7D%7C5%28%3F%3A[0-2]%5Cd%7C3[0-5]%29%29%29%7C%28%3F%3A[1-5]%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D%7C[6-9]%5Cd%7B0%2C2%7D%29%3F%5Cd) one:

```
6(?:[0-4]\d{3}|5(?:[0-4]\d{2}|5(?:[0-2]\d|3[0-5])))|(?:[1-5]\d{0,3}|[6-9]\d{0,2})?\d
```

The following Perl script tests some numbers:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $port = qr{
6(?:[0-4]\d{3}|5(?:[0-4]\d{2}|5(?:[0-2]\d|3[0-5])))|(?:[1-5]\d{0,3}|[6-9]\d{0,2})?\d
}x;

sub test {
  my ($label, $regexp, $start, $stop) = @_;
  my $matches = 0;
  my $tests = 0;
  foreach my $n ($start..$stop) {
    $tests++;
    $matches++ if "$n" =~ /^$regexp$/;
    $tests++;
    $matches++ if "0$n" =~ /^$regexp$/;
  }

  print "$label [$start $stop] => $matches matches in $tests tests\n";
}

test "Port", $port, 0, 2**16;
```

The output is:

```
Port [0 65536] => 65536 matches in 131074 tests
```