# Regex Validation for input LIMIT : 1- 65535

Tags: html, angularjs, regex

I am trying to Validate my port within the limit 1-65535 , but my validation is taking values till 69999 . It is not accepting 10000 also. Can you suggest me what's wrong in the Regex code.

```
ng-pattern="/^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|5\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,4})$/" required>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Anyone see anything wrong with my regex for port numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715064/anyone-see-anything-wrong-with-my-regex-for-port-numbers)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Regex for port numbers in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894771/regex-for-port-numbers-in-android)